# How I can apply conditional probability, formally, to this problem?

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed three times.

What is the probability of *two or more* heads given that there was at least one head?

I know, I could list out all the sample space and do some elementary probability and determine a straightforward answer. However, for all intents and purposes, I am trying to do this formally and that is where my intuition is breaking down. I really could use some help!

I would like to understand what is incorrect in my approach:

Let $A$ represent the event of two or more heads, and let $B$ represent at least one head. Respectively, we let $A_1$ represent the disjoint event of two heads and $A_3$ represent the event of three heads. Similarily for $B_1, B_2,$ and $B_3$.

We are trying to show that $P((A_1|B)\cup(A_2|B))$. That is, the probability of two heads given at least one head or the probability of three heads given at least one head.

This, by inclusion-exclusion principle is equal to $P(A_1|B) + P(A_2|B) - P((A_1|B)\cap(A_2|B))$.

However, just by looking at this now, I feel daunted that I am over complicating this problem completely.

Can anyone help me out here? I want to approach this problem with more than just intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't think what you're doing is clear and I think you have over complicated this. For example, it's not clear what $A_2$ is and I don't understand what "disjoint event of two heads" means.

> What is the probability of two or more heads given that there was at least one head?

We can use one variable, for example $N$. Let $N$ be the number of heads in 3 tosses.

Then the question becomes $P(N\geq 2| N\geq 1)$. Starting with the definition, we have
\begin{align*}
P(N\geq 2|N\geq 1) &= \frac{P(N\geq 2\cap N\geq 1)}{P(N\geq 1)}\\
&=\frac{P(N\geq 2)}{1-P(N=0)}\tag 1\\
&=\frac{P(N = 2)+P(N=3)}{1-P(N=0)}\tag 2\\
&=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3-2}+\binom{3}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3-3}}{1-\binom{3}{0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3-0}}\\
&=\frac{4}{7}
\end{align*}

where I noticed that $N$ follows a binomial distribution with $n = 3, p =1/2$, in $(1)$ the intersection of $N\geq 1$ and $N\geq 2$ is $N\geq 2$, and in $(2)$, \begin{align*}
P(N\geq 2) &= P(N = 2 \cup N=3)\\
&= P(N = 2)+P(N=3)-P(N=2\cap N = 3) \\
&= P(N = 2)+P(N=3)
\end{align*}
since $P(N=2\cap N=3) = P(\varnothing)=0$ because $N =2$ and $N = 3$ are disjoint. Also, I used the complement to find $P(N\geq 1)$ in $(1)$.

Comment: Right. You caught me back to earth. Thank you. Actually I like your solution. Can I ask what happened in the numerator on your (1) step? Why did P(N >= 2 and N >= 1) simply become P(N >=2)? Edit: DOH. INTERSECTION. Ignore this silly comment. Tired! Thanks again.

Comment: It happens. Good luck!